# Block particular website in android application without uninstalling it from device

Tags: android

How to develop an application in android that will block particular website in device without uninstalling it from device?

Comment: First off, to block websites on an Android device you either need to be a super-user (root access) or create a VPN filter. Neither of these are trivial. But I think you are misunderstanding something here, as a website is not "installed" on a device, so "uninstalling" makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 2):

If Android OS on the phone is not rooted you won't be able to block another application. Os doesn't give rights to do that. Android runs on Linux, Linux provides sandbox system call API and dictates rules.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

Basically you can do what is allowed to do. Intercept call's, block camera via device admin manager, read data of another apps if they share that data and only what they share, use some common resources, but not more than that. To do what you want to do your app has to be a root, but standard third party apps don't get root privileges. And your solution is to change firmware, bind your app into it with root privileges.

Though some application gives the same functionality. Those apps apparently pre-built with Android firmware. Manufacturers get firmware before it goes to the rest of the world. Make necessary changes to give more privileges to their app and bind it with Android ROM. You cannot uninstall those apps.

The only resolution is could prefer is to have root privileges to block other apps. And you will only get them on a rooted device.

Comment: How about  internet filtering by my app,
I want to write a parental-control app.